# Date sequences to remain intact after sorting

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I want to set up a schedule in a Google Sheet with a start date and then adding additional dates depending the frequency of visits and the type of client. This could be weekly, bi-weekly, monthly, etc.. I want these dates to be dynamic so a change in an earlier date will cascade down to the remaining dates. I know I can do this with one client, but I want to be able to sort all of the clients and not lose the accuracy of the dates and their ability to show future dates.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Date | Weekly |
| Client 1 | AboveDate+7 | Weekly |
| Client 1 | AboveDate+7 | Weekly |
| Client 2 | Date2 | Bi-Weekly |
| Client 2 | AboveDate+14 | Bi-Weekly |
| Client 2 | AboveDate+14 | Bi-Weekly |

I tried referencing date cells and adding the number of days to the date cell and the copying down. This is fine until you sort the dates. I tried using absolute cell references, but that didn't work either.

Comment: can you share a sample sheet with example of your data and desired result? You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: I created a sheet per your suggestion called Visit dates (20 Feb 04:48). If I sort by visit date, all of the date references are messed up.  How do I share the sheet?  Does this link work for you? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/164n0fsmKfBRoUPoBcUn8uV6nrXDmZEWqLb-4gGCrRL8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you Tedinoz. How would you assign the date based on the previous value for that client?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But related question: [Repeat cell values and increment them afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72264626/1330560) is an example of a formula that references the original row data and builds an new output range. Still not sortable. I think a `LAMBDA` formula that _includes_ sort might offer a solution.

Answer (score 1):

To get a sorted *copy* of the data, **Insert > Sheet** and use `query()`, like this:

```
=query(Sheet1!A1:C13, "order by B", 1)
```

To sort the data in place, copy and paste the dates column over itself using **Edit > Paste special > Paste values only**. That replaces formulas with static data, after which sorting works normally.

A third option is to replace the `Date` column with a `Start date` column that only has a date in the first row per each client. The dates per each visit can then be calculated automatically in a new `Date` column like this:

```
=vstack( 
  "Date", 
  map(A2:A, B2:B, C2:C, lambda(client, date, freq, to_date( 
    ifs( 
      isblank(client), iferror(ø), 
      isnumber(date), date, 
      true, let( 
        first, xlookup(client, A2:A, B2:B), 
        count, rows(filter(first:date, offset(first:date, 0, -1) = client)) - 1, 
        diff, count * if(freq = "Bi-weekly", 14, 7), 
        first + diff 
      ) 
    ) 
  ))) 
)
```

The formula must go to row 1. The sheet can then be sorted by the new column normally. See the [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/164n0fsmKfBRoUPoBcUn8uV6nrXDmZEWqLb-4gGCrRL8/edit#gid=828374091).